# Where are my incompatible apps?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

After installing an OS X upgrade (Mountain Lion) a pop up told me that my incompatible applications have been moved. How do I find them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installing Mountain Lion any applications that the installer determines to be incompatible with the new system are moved to a folder named **Incompatible Software** (located in the top level directory of the startup disk, i.e., the disk where your home folder is located).

One of many ways to get to that folder is to open a Finder window and then press Command-Shift-G; specifying a "/" (forward slash, without the quotes) for the folder name should take you to the folder containing **Incompatible Software**.